# What is the meaning of "with at least one of the words. without the words. where my words occur"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

Searching for google scholar in the search engine duck duck go gives this cryptic sounding help text. "with at least one of the words. without the words. where my words occur".

What does it mean? Even if it is a glitch, where did it come from?

Here is what I came up with so far.

- **where my words occur** - Its a text field so words should occur here.
- **without the words** - The intended words did not get displayed due to a glitch.
- **with at least one of the words** - The error message showed up in the text field instead of the real message. So, at least one of the words occurred.

Its keeping me up at night.

[image]

Comment: It's a list of options.

Comment: I think it's a product of the way DuckDuckGo's web crawler has indexed Google Scholar's site.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is relevant to this site. Is there a problem with understanding the meaning of the sentence fragments *themselves*? Or is this asking for an explanation of how Duck Duck Go works?

Comment: I am interested in the sentence fragments. DDG is a search engine. I understand how search engines work. I just could not find where the crawler extracted these phrases from.

Comment: @Souradeep Nanda - "I just could not find where the crawler extracted these phrases from." They are in the Advanced Search dialog, reached from the Google Scholar "burger menu".

Comment: really? Could you post the whole text, please?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a question about the English language, it is about why a search engine displays particular text from a site. The answer being that... that text is on the site. Following the link would show where the text appears on the site and answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are standard search queries. A typo of bug is showing them instead of the results. So, for example, the most common instance of a search would be when you want to see any web page **with at least one of the word you typed**.

Alternatively, say you are searching for a lawyer, but all you get are results of *traffic* or *divorce* law, and neither one of thees helps at all. In this case, you would want to run a search for *lawyer*, but only view results **without the words** "traffic" or "divorce".

You can see them in [this screenshot](https://kek.gg/i/7yd3BG.png)